# Computational geometry, tetrahedron signed volume

Tags: math, geometry

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here goes...

**Short version:** I'm trying to compute the orientation of a triangle on a plane, formed by the intersection of 3 edges, without explicitly computing the intersection points.

**Long version:** I need to triangulate a PSLG on a triangle in 3D. The vertices of the PSLG are defined by the intersections of line segments with the plane through the triangle, and are guaranteed to lie within the triangle. Assuming I had the intersection points, I could project to 2D and use a point-line-side (or triangle signed area) test to determine the orientation of a triangle between any 3 intersection points.

The problem is I can't explicitly compute the intersection points because of the floating-point error that accumulates when I find the line-plane intersection. To figure out if the line segments strike the triangle in the first place, I'm using some freely available robust geometric predicates, which give the sign of the volume of a tetrahedron, or equivalently which side of a plane a point lies on. I can determine if the line segment endpoints are on opposite sides of the plane through the triangle, then form tetrahedra between the line segment and each edge of the triangle to determine whether the intersection point lies within the triangle.

Since I can't explicitly compute the intersection points, I'm wondering if there is a way to express the same 2D orient calculation in 3D using only the original points. If there are 3 edges striking the triangle that gives me 9 points in total to play with. Assuming what I'm asking is even possible (using only the 3D orient tests), then I'm guessing that I'll need to form some subset of all the possible tetrahedra between those 9 points. I'm having difficultly even visualizing this, let alone distilling it into a formula or code. I can't even google this because I don't know what the industry standard terminology might be for this type of problem.

Any ideas how to proceed with this?  Thanks.  Perhaps I should ask MathOverflow as well...

EDIT: After reading some of the comments, one thing that occurs to me... Perhaps if I could fit non-overlapping tetrahedra between the 3 line segments, then the orientation of any one of those that crossed the plane would be the answer I'm looking for. Other than when the edges enclose a simple triangular prism, I'm not sure this sub-problem is solvable either.

EDIT: The requested image.
[image]

Comment: I would recommend MathOverflow for this.  I'm not saying that there's not anyone here who could solve it, just that you'd probably get an answer faster there (and you wouldn't risk your question being closed as not programming-related).

Comment: Are the line segments orthogonal to the triangle?

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Maybe a diagram would help.

Comment: Is one of the line segement allowed to intersect the (possbily non-planar) non-selfintersecting quadrilateral formed by the four points defining the other two line segments?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I understood it as follows - you are given three points defining a plane and three pairs of points (one point on each side of the plane) defining three line segments. Now determine if the three intersection points of the line segments with the plane are in (counter)clockwise order.

Comment: "Are the line segments orthogonal to the triangle?" -- No, the only constraint is that one endpoint of each edge is above the plane, and the other endpoint below it. The intersection points are guaranteed to lie within the triangle.
"Is one of the line segement allowed to intersect the (possbily non-planar) non-selfintersecting quadrilateral formed by the four points defining the other two line segments?" -- Yes.

Comment: If the line segments happen to be orthogonal, then the volume between the line segments is a triangular prism, and I can take 3 points above and 1 below to form a tet which will tell me the orientation of the triangle where that prism intersects the plane. The problem is mainly with the case where it doesn't form a prism. Thanks.

Comment: Link to question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31578

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering this on both MO & SO, expanding the comments I made on MO.

My sense is that no computational trick with signed tetrahedra volumes will avoid the precision issues that are your main concern. This is because, if you have tightly twisted segments, the orientation of the triangle depends on the precise positioning of the cutting plane.

[image removed; see below]
In the above example, the upper plane crosses the segments in the order (*a,b,c*) [ccw from above]: (*red,blue,green*), while the lower plane crosses in the reverse order (*c,b,a*): (*green,blue,red*). The height
of the cutting plane could be determined by your last bit of precision.

Consequently, I think it makes sense to just go ahead and compute the points of intersection in
the cutting plane, using enough precision to make the computation exact.  If your segment endpoints coordinates and plane coefficients have *L* bits of precision, then there is just a small constant-factor increase needed.  Although I am not certain of precisely what that factor is, it is small--perhaps 4.  You will not need e.g., *L*<sup>2</sup> bits, because the computation is solving linear equations.
So there will not be an explosion in the precision required to compute this exactly.

Good luck!

(I was prevented from posting the clarifying image because I don't have the reputation. See
the [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31578/computational-geometry-tetrahedron-signed-volume/31695#31695) instead.)

**Edit**: Do see the MO answer, but here's the image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll get an AP lib from somewhere and do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would write symbolic vector equations, you know, with dot and cross products, to find the normal of the intersection triangle. Then, the sign of the dot product of this normal with the initial triangle one gives the orientation. So finally you can express this in a form sign(F(p1,...,p9)), where p1 to p9 are your points and F() is an ugly formula including dot and cross products of differences (pi-pj). Don't know if this can be done simpler, but this general approach does the job.

Comment: I see what you mean, I could write out the formula, but I think that leaves me an even greater problem to solve though: how to determine what the sign will be. This is same kind of problem that the predicates I'm already using solve, finding the sign of a determinant robustly. I'm struggling to understand how they work, so I'm not optimistic I'll be able to construct a new predicate along the same lines.

Comment: If there was a purely geometric interpretation of the answer, then I could use the canned predicates I already have.

Comment: Well, I agree that there can be some numerical issues when computing the formula F(p1,...,p9). For example, if A is huge with respect to b, then (A-A)+b == b but (A+b)-A == 0. However, such things come into play when you are operating with really huge differences between the numbers (as you need to go below the 10^-16 double precision). Of course, it would be simpler/better to use an existing workaround, but then you have to find it first.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have three lines intersecting the plane, and you want to calculate the orientation of the triangle formed by the intersection points, without calculating the intersection points themselves?

If so:  you have a plane

```
N·(x - x0) = 0
```

and six points...

```
l1a, l1b, l2a, l2b, l3a, l3b
```

...forming three lines

```
l1 = l1a + t(l1b - l1a)
l2 = l2a + u(l2b - l2a)
l3 = l3a + v(l3b - l3a)
```

The intersection points of these lines to the plane occur at specific values of t, u, v, which I'll call t<sub>i</sub>, u<sub>i</sub>, v<sub>i</sub>

```
N·(l1a + ti(l1b - l1a) - x0) = 0

      N·(x0 - l1a)
ti =  ----------------
      N·(l1b - l1a)
(similarly for ui, vi)
```

Then the specific points of intersection are

```
intersect1 = l1a + ti(l1b - l1a)
intersect2 = l2a + ui(l2b - l2a)
intersect3 = l3a + vi(l3b - l3a)
```

Finally, the orientation of your triangle is

```
orientation = direction of (intersect2 - intersect1)x(intersect3 - intersect1)
```

*(x is cross-product)* Work backwards plugging the values, and you'll have an equation for orientation based only on N, x<sub>0</sub>, and your six points.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I know I can symbolically write that, or numerically compute it. The problem is how to do it without running afoul of precision issues. It would be equivalent work to reinventing the predicates I mentioned above, something that is beyond my abilities. Ideally I'm looking for some geometric interpretation of the answer that allows me to reuse the predicates I already have.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your triangle vertices `T[0]`, `T[1]`, `T[2]`, and the first line segment's endpoints are `L[0]` and `L[1]`, the second is `L[2]` and `L[3]`, and the third is `L[4]` and `L[5]`. I imagine you want a function

```
int Orient(Pt3 T[3], Pt3 L[6]); // index L by L[2*i+j], i=0..2, j=0..1
```

which returns 1 if the intersections have the same orientation as the triangle, and -1 otherwise. 
The result should be symmetric under interchange of `j` values, antisymmetric under interchange of `i` values and `T` indices. As long as you can compute a quantity with these symmetries, that's all you need.

Let's try

```
Sign(Product( Orient3D(T[i],T[i+1],L[2*i+0],L[2*i+1]) * -Orient3D(T[i],T[i+1],L[2*i+1],L[2*i+0]) ), i=0..2))
```

where the product should be taken over cyclic permutations of the indices (modulo 3). I believe this has all the symmetry properties required. `Orient3D` is Shewchuk's 4-point plane orientation test, which I assume you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a whirl. If it underflows or doesn't work out then I'll probably do what Joseph is suggesting and use an arbitrary prec library.

Comment: Well, you should distribute the Sign function to each of he Orient3D's to prevent underflow.

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but each orient3d looks as though it forms a tetrahedron between an edge of the triangle and a line segment. The 2nd orient reverses the segment so the tet sign is opposite, then the negate makes it the same again. Assuming all the segments have their 1st vertex above the plane and their 2nd below, all the 1st orients produce positive sign (for all edges and segments), as all the line/plane intersections are within the triangle. The final result looks like it's always +1.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. I had my doubts about the correctness of the code above when I posted it, and I made a ton of edits before I gave up. The point I was trying to make was that if you can come up with a quantity with the right symmetries, then you have all you need. Not sure if this approach will be fruitful, but just an idea.