# Find a 4 points that form a tetrahedron around some point

Tags: c#, c++, math, geometry

There is an array of points in 3 dimentions. `1 = {x,y,z}; 2 = {x,y,z}; 3 = {x,y,z}, ... n = {x,y,z}`. Also we have a point `t = {x,y,z}`.
How to spot a 4 points that form a tetrahedron around point `t`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a `1` to all your coordinates, effectively turning them into homogeneous coordinates. Then the sign of the determinant of the matrix formed by four such coordinate verctors tells you the orientation of the resulting tetrahedron. Or in other words, if you fix three points and plug in various vectors as the fourth, the resulting signs will tell you whether the fourth point is above of below the plane spanned by the first three.

Now you can build an algorithm from this. Start by choosing a triple of points. Then a fourth point is a valid coordinate only if it lies on the same side of the plane spanned by the first three as `t`. Multiply the signs, and if the result is positive you can continue. Check the other three sides of the resulting tetrahedron, and if `t` is inside all four, you are done. You could code this e.g. like this:

```python
for i1 from 1 to n:
  for i2 from i1 + 1 to n:
    for i3 from i2 + 1 to n:
      for i4 from i3 + 1 to n:
        o = orient(i1, i2, i3, i4)
        if (orient(i1, i2, i3, t)*o > 0 and orient(i1, i2, t, i4)*o > 0 and
            orient(i1, t, i3, i4)*o > 0 and orient(t, i2, i3, i4)*o > 0):
          solution(i1, i2, i3, i4)
```

The function `orient` here is the determinant computation outlined above.

Comment: This sound interesting, do you have a reference for this technique?

Comment: @AndrewWalker: Learned this in a lecture, but http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html mentions it (2d case on that page, but 3d in the code and paper), and that gets [referenced](http://mathoverflow.net/q/99870/25563) [a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3233963/1468366). [Wikipedia: Curve orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation) uses similar ideas, 2d only though. Many 2d implementations have code for a counterclockwise predicate, often written `ccw`. Which brings me to http://voronoi.com/wiki/index.php?title=Vector_Algebra_%26_Geometry covering 3d as well.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on @MvG. Using the [Hesse normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form) for a surface `n⋅r−d=0` where `n` is a unit normal `r` is a point on a surface and `d` is distance from the point to a surface. Given three points on a surface `p1`, `p2`, `p3` a normal is

```
n = (p2-p1) ^ (p3-p1)
```

Where ^ is the cross product. This is not unit length but thats not important. We can test whether a target point `q` is on the surface by calculating

```
n . q  - n . p1
```

If it is zero then q is on the surface, otherwise the sign determines which side of the surface you are on. Note `n . q` is just the [Triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) `(a ^ b) . q` which is expressed as a determinant. So our test is

triple( p2 - p1, p3 - p1, q ) - triple( p2 - p1, p3 - p1, p1 ).

Do this for each triple of points, and compare signs of t and forth point in the tetrahedron, as in MvG's solution. In fact if you do work out the algebra it should be the same test.

An optimisation it might be worth calculating before hand is that the x-coordinate of t must not be smaller that the minimum x-coord of the other points. Similar of max and min of x, y, and z. This might save a lot of multiplications.

Answer (score 0):

Just a rough idea - the four points in question must have the same distance from `t` and must be pairwise in the same angle of 109.5°; might be a bit fiddlish to do in code though.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, OP doesn't require a *regular* tetrahedron *centered* in `t`, but instead any tetrahedron with corners chosen from the given set that contains `t`. Although he didn't say so very clearly.